# Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, policy, amazon-kms

Terraform apply complains that `Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals` upon KMS key creation with policies:

```
     -----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2023-03-29T17:08:19.091Z
     2023-03-29T17:08:19.091Z [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.0.0_x5: [aws-sdk-go] {"__type":"MalformedPolicyDocumentException","message":"Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals."}: timestamp=2023-03-29T17:08:19.091Z
     2023-03-29T17:08:19.091Z [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.0.0_x5: [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response kms/CreateKey failed, attempt 0/25, error MalformedPolicyDocumentException: Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals.: timestamp=2023-03-29T17:08:19.091Z
     2023-03-29T17:08:23.094Z [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.0.0_x5: [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request kms/CreateKey Details:
```

Policies:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:root"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow key administration to the Account."
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:List*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "<account-id>"
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sqs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow SQS to use the key"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:List*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "<account-id>"
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow S3 to use the key"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/data-monitoring-service-account"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow IAM role to use the key"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:List*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "<account-id>"
        }
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow EC2 to use the key"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/af-service-account"
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Sid": "Allow IAM role to use the key"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2008-10-17"
}
```

`<account-id>` is something like `074150055827`.

Could you please review policies?

Answer (score 2):

This may be cause by the [old version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html) of the policy document.  Try with a new version.